# How was Voyager able to transport the medicine while the Vidiian shields were up?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Star Trek: Voyager episode "Resolutions", how did they transport the cure for the disease from the Vidiians through the Vidiian shields which were up?

If Voyager can't get it to transport through it's own shields how could it possibly know how to get it through the Vidiians shields? Voyager had to drop it's own shields to get the medicine through.

Comment: @Lexible Now those were good edits. I'm getting lazy and sleepy. It's after midnight here, been a long day, and I've been saving up a lot of questions from episodes that I've watched recently. Trying to "unload" some of them, so to speak. I'll try to pay better attention in the titles and headings, as well as capitalization of proper nouns, well sort of proper nouns, kind of like elf? Dwarf? orc? Ugh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr Pel was on the Vidiian ship and clearly had arranged a covert channel of communication with which to speak with her friends on the Voyager.

It's perfectly reasonable to assume that she would have the technical wherewithal (either through her own knowledge or in cahoots with the Voyager crew) to arrange for the shields on her ship to come down at the right time, presumably by sabotaging the emitters, the power supply or simply by giving the Voyager crew the Vidiian ship's [shield frequency.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Battle_of_Veridian_III#Prelude).

Since her ship wasn't destroyed by the anti-matter blast (e.g. its shields must have been in place a few seconds later), my guess would be that it was the latter.